# What is the historical origin of the story of the Temptation of Christ?

Tags: ancient-history, christianity, archaeology, bible, jesus

In the New Testament of the Christian Bible, there is a story in which Jesus meets the Christian Devil (Satan), and Satan tempts Jesus to give up his mission through promises of power.

I want more historical information about this story, especially since I know that authors wrote the canonized Gospels at least three decades after Jesus's death. I also know that later scribes intentionally and accidentally rewrote parts of the Bible.

Was the Temptation of Christ part of the original Gospels, or was it added later? Where did this story come from? Was this story from any previous myths about divine humans? Why was this story written? Was the story intended to be biographical or metaphorical? Where did the writer receive his information/inspiration for this story?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best place for this sort of question. Of the multiple questions that you ask, most are going to be opinion-based (those of faith will assert that God is the inspiration or possibly even the 'author' of the stories). You should narrow things down to just what can be answered historically.

Comment: There are some things that can be said historically about the [life of Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_Jesus). Sadly, this turns out not to be among them, but I'm not entirely sure the poster should be expected to know that before asking.

Answer (score 7):

This is one of the things that only appears in the [synoptic Gospels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synoptic_Gospels), which of course are assumed to have shared sources, but not in John. As such, it effectively comes to us through only once source, and thus it isn't one of the [things in the Gospels that we can talk about as historical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_Jesus#Consensual_knowledge_about_Jesus).

[image]

As for what we do have, both Luke and Matthew copied the material from (the older) Mark, and then added their own elaboration to the story. However, they were clearly differently authored, as different things happened in them, and in different orders.

So what does that leave us with historically? Not much. If you want to read the original core of the story, read the account in Mark. But realize that even there, its likely just a story created by the author of Mark, not something intended to be a historical account. As with most of The Bible, its true value is spiritual, not historical.

Comment: This isn't actually correct, according to the dominant model of the gospel formation. There are details found in Mt and Lk against Mk, which suggest it also comes from Q. That gives us two sources, not just one. That said, it's not historical not because of the sources, but because it doesn't purport to be a true witness. If only Jesus was there, and there's no mention of him mentioning this episode, how would anyone know about it? Why should we believe him?

Comment: Also, the presence of supernatural beings is a big strike against it. If I remember correctly, there was no desert temptation adopted by the [Jesus Seminar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_Seminar).

Comment: @cmw - The problem there is that there's some supernatural stuff (not a lot, but some) that is rather well supported. That doesn't mean that the historian has to accept that supernatural stuff actually occurred, just that the observers at the time believed it did.

Comment: Even then, a mythos can spring up shortly after death, but yeah, I suppose it's possible that this episode was believed to have happened by contemporaries, but since Mark and Q (and Thomas) aren't really historical texts, they don't really provide that sort of evidence. It's quite complicated, though.